# Testing in-app billing with your products

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In testing with your products what happens in the inn-app billing if you do not have a credit card associated with your account?

Comment: No credit card is needed for In-App testing replace your Product ID with `android.test.purchased`

Comment: I'm trying to test the in-app billing with my products before proceeding with the publication of my application. The testing works perfectly and I have orders registered in Google Wallet. Now I have discovered that on some devices the method requestPurchase() does not show the alert to GooglePlay. The only difference was that I had for this account does not have a credit card linked.